# How to check the hashmap value is present or not in jstl

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jstl

In my contoller i have a map object like below.

```
 Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
     Map<TblProjectPhase, List<TblProjectResource>> result=new HashMap<TblProjectPhase,List<TblProjectResource>>();
     model.put("userList", result);
```

i am going to check the List TblProjectResource  value is empty like below.

```
<c:when test="${model.userList.size()>0}">
<c:forEach var="user" items="${model.userList}">
    <c:if test="${not empty user.value}">
     hello
   </c:if>
</c:when>
```

The problem of the above approach is hello prints more than one.How to i check List this list size is greater than zero without using foreach.

Any Ideas will be greatly appreciated!!!!

Comment: You are already testing that the list size is greater than 0 in your c:when. So, what is the question?

Comment: i want to check this List<TblProjectResource> size greater than zero.In c:when i checked map object result not List<TblProjectResource>.

Comment: You have 0, one or more such lists, each stored under a different key (of type TblProjectPhase) in the map. So, which one do you want to test?

Comment: i want to  check the fist one.

Comment: Maps don't have any order. There is no first one. That doesn't make much sense. You should probably not use a Map.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Is it possible to make my c:if executes only ones?

Comment: Sure. Do it as you would in Java (that's probably what you should do BTW: put that logic in the controller): initialize a variable to true (using c:set), then start iterating. Only execute the body of the loop if the variable is true, and set it to false (still using c:set) after the first iteration. This shows a serious design problem, though. I can't imagine why you would check the "first" value in the map, since the first element could be anything.